# The Standard Model Lagrangian vs experimental results

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model, scattering-cross-section

In the Standard Model of particle physics, one always shows the general SM Lagrangian and claims that the SM can be summarised in the expression. But it's not clear to me how this is actually verified experimentally. We measure cross sections most of the times, but can anyone help me make the direct link to the SM Lagrangian when we do measurements? How do you go from the Lagrangian to the cross sections?

Comment: Technically this is the entire basis of a course in quantum field theory, are you familiar with aspects of QFT?

Comment: Yes, but I lost the link with the Lagrangian from the Matrix elements, from which we can calculate cross sections. So I'm naively looking for a clear answer on how to link the two ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To naively answer this question:

- Take the interaction term(s) in your Lagrangian
- Perform the S-matrix expansion up to n-th order
- Derive the Feynman rules
- Calculate the Feynman amplitudes of the processes you're interested
- Use the Feynman amplitude squared term to calculate the cross sections / decay rates

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! However, I was wondering if I can find an example somewhere, where these steps are shown?

Comment: I think all qft books cover those steps like: An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory by Daniel V. Schroeder and Michael Peskin, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model by Matthew D. Schwartz, Field Quantization by W. Greiner J. Reinhardt, Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur by Stephen Blundell and Tom Lancaster...